# show changes in target spark dataframe on changes in source spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, formatting

please help me solve following problem

source spark dataframe -:

```
+---+-------+-------+
|key|   city|flag   |
+---+-------+-------+
|  1|  Noida|active |
|  2|Gurgaon|active |
|  3|  Delhi|active |
+---+-------+-------+
```

target spark dataframe-:

```
+---+-------+------------+-------------+
|key|   city|sarogate_key|flag         |
+---+-------+------------+-------------+
|  1| Noida|           1|active    |
|  3|  Delhi|           3|active       |
|  2|Gurgaon|           2|active       |
+---+-------+------------+-------------+
```

in source spark dataframe key 1 city changes from Noida to Mumbai

```
+---+-------+-------+
|key|   city|flag   |
+---+-------+-------+
|  1|  Mumbai|active |
|  2|Gurgaon|active |
|  3|  Delhi|active |
+---+-------+-------+
```

now we need to change target spark dataframe to in following formate with history maintained

```
+---+-------+------------+-------------+
|key|   city|sarogate_key|flag         |
+---+-------+------------+-------------+
|  1| Noida|            1|de-active    |
|  3|  Delhi|           3|active       |
|  2|Gurgaon|           2|active       |
+---+-------+------------+-------------+
| 4 | Mumbai |          4| active      |
+---+-------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: are you looking solution for spark streaming?

Comment: i need solution without using Spark SQL & streaming, only use spark Data set API

Comment: ok. so what do you mean by update the source dataframe? how do you do that?

Comment: in target dataframe history should be maintained if any changes in source dataframe

Comment: in spark you cannot actually update a dataframe. its always transformation. you see. it doesn't work like other databases. thats why i asked how you want to update the dataframe.

Comment: you can use withColumn and when function combined. if you want to see how I can answer that.

Comment: can you provide some lines of code to proceed me